# Finding Analytic Functions that Satisfy Certain Conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

How would one go about finding:

1. All analytic f such that $|f''(x)|>|e^{7z}|$?
2. All analytic functions such that $f(z) = z + f(z^2)$.
3. All linear functions that map from the punctured unit disk to itself.

Any hints would be much appreciated.  I am not really sure how to give a general form as these questions ask.

Comment: Here's a hint for #2: what is $f(1)$?

Comment: I'll think about that Umberto, I don't see it immediately.  I should note these problems are from a past exam, but it is possible they meant entire.  I have seen similar questions phrased that way instead and it does seem to make more sense.

Comment: Writing "analytic" without a specific domain could conceivably mean "entire", although on an exam question you'd expect more precise statements.